# Padding not affecting child in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is there any reason why padding does not affect the children of an element in internet Explorer (tested on IE 11)?

As a very simple example:

```css
main {
  padding: 32px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
    This is just a test...
  </p>
</main>
```

I would expect the paragraph to be padded (which is the case in all modern browsers I tried it on), but for some reason, the padding has no effect in Internet Explorer...

Could anyone be able to explain this problem and how to get around it? I would spontaneously thought of something like `main > * { padding:inherit }`, but this would obviously not be the greatest of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for some reason IE give `<main>` a CSS attribute of `display: inline;`. To make sure it works the same with chrome just add `display: block;` to you `<main>` tag.

Comment: It's becuase IE doesn't support the HTML5 `<main>` element..and so it *defaults* to the ***initial*** state which is `display:inline`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @Paulie_D